# Is This An Example Of Recursion (Python)

Tags: python, validation, recursion

Hi I am struggling to understand exactly what recursion is, It is a requirement of the program I am writing(a snake game) and I cannot find a clear definition of what is classified as recursion. Could someone tell me if the code below is an example of this?

`while True:
    #recieve input
    player_name = input("Enter a name between 0 and 20 characters: ")
    #if length is within boundaries the loop is stopped
    if len(player_name) > 0 and len(player_name) <= 20: break
    #if the name is outwith the boundaries a message is printed and the loop restarts
    print("Too long/short, try again.")`

Comment: No this isn't recursion; you need something lie a function that calls itself for recursion

Comment: No, this is not an example of recursion. Recursion requires a function calling itself.

Comment: while loop is not recursion.

Comment: Recursion is just having a function recall itself WITHIN the function, example `def something(): print('a'); something()` .

Comment: If you're required to write it, it must be for some sort of homework or something, and I bet there's some kind of instructional material that accompanies it - it should contain an explanation of recursion.

Comment: Search in google, may be you can find some examples to write recursive function. For e.g., look at here https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/recursion

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of looping:

**1. Iteration:**

Here you use for(), while(), do-while() loops to repeat a set of statements

**2. Recursion:**

Here you call a function which calls the same function from within.

Example:

```
def factorial(n):
if n == 0:
    return 1
else:
    return n * factorial(n - 1)
```

Here the function *factorial()* is calling itself until value of n becomes 0. The statement *n==0* is called base/terminal condition which terminates the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You have recursion when you define something in terms of itself. For example, the following definition of "walk staircase" is recursive:

> "walk staircase" :=
>
> if there's a step left: take a step and "walk staircase"
> else if there's no step left: stop

In programming recursion is most often seen in the form of recursive function definitions, that is functions that call themselves.

Here's an example function that computes the sum 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n for some number n > 0.

```
>>> def cumsum(n):
...     if n == 1:
...         return n
...     else:
...         return n + cumsum(n - 1)
... 
>>> cumsum(5)
15
>>> 1+2+3+4+5
15
```

What makes this function recursive is the fact that `cumsum` is used in the definition on `cumsum` itself.

Since you don't have any recursive calls in your code, it is not an example of recursion. Your `while True` loop is an example of iteration.